# Why does the rest of the code I wrote not work?

Tags: python, windows, debugging, pycharm

**i wanted to change this original code to what i think,**

```
num1 = float(input('enter your first number :'))
op = input('choose your operator: ')
num2 = float(input('enter your second number :'))


if op == '-':
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op == '+':
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op == '*':
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op == '/':
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print('invalid operator')
```

**and changed to this.
but it only shows first operation which is : -**

```
**num1 = float(input('enter your first number :'))
op = input('choose your operator: ')
num2 = float(input('enter your second number :'))
operator = ('+', '-', '/', '*')

if op in operator:
    print(num1 - num2)
elif op in operator:
    print(num1 + num2)
elif op in operator:
    print(num1 * num2)
elif op in operator:
    print(num1 / num2)
else:
    print('invalid operator')
```

i was trying to change first code (the original)
to the second code that i wanted to code it as myself.
but it only shows first operator which is : -
where i did wrong?

Comment: Why would you expect multiple different identical elifs to be hit instead of the if?

Comment: @Sayse so What should I do to get a better result and show me the rest of the results code?

Comment: Revert to your original code?

Comment: @Sayse you know, Since I just started learning, it is very important for me to be able to get results through other ways.
It is more important for me to be able to get results through a way other than the main way.

Comment: @Crashofs in that case, explain why you expect `if op in operator:` to be False, but **exactly same condition** two lines later in `elif op in operator:` should be True, and we can go from there.

Comment: @matszwecja thanks for response, so what i should do now?
if i want to write it

Comment: Answer the question I asked. Knowing why code doesn't work is just as important as knowing why it does work. Did you understand why 2nd code doesn't work?

Comment: @matszwecja I expect that with the help of the commands that I used, every time I make a condition, it will look at my list or tuple and use one of the operators requested by the user on the next lines.

Comment: @Crashofs No, that's what you **want** the code to do. I asked if you understand why 2nd code **doesn't** do that.

Comment: @matszwecja i really don't know,

Comment: Writing `operator = ('+', '-', '/', '*')` you create a tuple of characters. So `if op in operator` means "is `op` in the tuple?": this condition will be true with any "+-*/" character.  The `elif`/`else` part will be checked only if the first condition is false, which is not the case

Comment: @Crashofs can you explain your reasoning behind the second code? That way we can figure out where your thought process went wrong. (If you ask us "how can I write it correctly?", we'll just tell you to do it like the first code, and that does not seem to be what you want.)

Comment: Okay, so let's run it through - you get `op` from user, and then check if it's in `('+', '-', '/', '*')`. Is that right? And let's say `op` is `*`. Is `* in ('+', '-', '/', '*')` True?

Comment: @LorenzoMogicato thanks for respond :)
you know i was trying to find a way to change somethings in original code and make a new way to resolve.

Comment: @slothrop I can't say exactly why I expect this to happen because I was trying to find a new way to solve this problem with the things I've learned so far compared to the original version, which I now understand that you have to use more advanced features that I still don't know. I didn't get to use it.
I was mostly trying to be creative and find out if there is a way similar to my way or not?

Comment: "*I was mostly trying to be creative and find out if there is a way similar to my way or not*" Cool. So we want to know what "your way" is :) Can you sum up **how** you want your code to be different to the first code that you posted?

Comment: @matszwecja yeah it only runs my first ```if``` and not other ```elif```'s

Comment: @Crashofs what do you understand the difference between `if` and `elif` to be?

Comment: @slothrop yes of course.
I wanted to use ```lists``` instead of ```==``` and ask the program to bring the operator desired by the user in the variables and show the result.
According to the little knowledge I have at the moment, of course :)

Comment: Correct! `op in operator` will be always True (or False) through all the program. Checking it again and again doesn't make sense. If it's False once, all the other if statements will be False as well!

Comment: @Crashofs got it. So using a list (or tuple) might be useful if you want several items to result in the same behaviour, i.e. your code asks "is `x` one of the items in `y`? I don't care which specific item, just tell me yes or no, is it one of the items?". However, that's not so useful here because every one of the four operators needs to have different behaviour.

Comment: But imagine you wanted the user to be able to enter either `x` or `*` as a multiplication symbol. In that case, you might want to do `if op in ('x', '*'):`

Comment: @LorenzoMogicato so what can i do with these items that i'm using in my code to get a right result ? with ```and```, ```in```, ```list```
can you help me please ?

Comment: @slothrop so you're telling me that i can't use ```and```,```in```,```list``` in these code with these parameters and expect the right result?

Comment: You could, but it's kind of unnecessary. You can write `if op in ['*']:` for example, but it doesn't really give a benefit compared to `if op == '*':` It's a bit like asking "what can I use this hammer for?" rather than "what's the best tool to tighten this screw?" for example :)

Comment: As @slothrop said, every case has a different behaviour (add/subtract/etc): you cannot use `op in operator`.     `op in ('+')` works tho, even if it doesn't make any sense (`op == '+'` is preferable)

Comment: thanks a lot to your guys for helping me.
thanks for your time. <3 @LorenzoMogicato

Comment: thanks a lot to your guys for helping me. thanks for your time. <3 @slothrop

Answer (score 0):

The following is essentially what has been suggested with lambda expressions, but in my opinion this is more readable. If you make use of the built-in module operator, you can use a dictionary to nicely translate input into an operator:

```
import operator as ops 

num1 = float(input('enter your first number :'))
op = input('choose your operator: ')
num2 = float(input('enter your second number :'))

# setting up a dictionary to translate the input to an operator, 
operator = {'+': ops.add, '-': ops.sub, '*': ops.mul, '/': ops.truediv}

if op in operator.keys(): # operator.keys() is equivalent to ('+', '-', '*', '/')
    print(operator[op](num1, num2))
else:
    print('invalid operator')
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe this must be something you are trying to acheive:

```py
num1 = float(input('enter your first number :'))
op = str(input('choose your operator: '))
num2 = float(input('enter your second number :'))

if op in ('+', '-', '/', '*'):
    if op == '+':
        print(num1 + num2)
    elif op == '-':
        print(num1 - num2)
    elif op == '*':
        print(num1 * num2)
    elif op == '/':
        print(num1 / num2)
else:
    raise ValueError("Invalid operator!")
```

Comment: thanks for your response.
So then the == symbol should have been used anyway, right?
Unless I was using more advanced features that I haven't learned yet

Answer (score -2):

in your code, op in operator is always true. so the first if condition always be executed.

I gauss you need a dict to store the function of the op.

```
num1 = float(input('enter your first number :'))
op = input('choose your operator: ')
num2 = float(input('enter your second number :'))

operator = {
    "-": lambda x, y: x - y,
    "+": lambda x, y: x + y,
    "/": lambda x, y: x / y,
    "*": lambda x, y: x * y
    }

if op in operator:
    print(operator[op](num1, num2))
else:
    print('invalid operator')
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @slothrop I modify the answer. the first if is always true in your code. so your get num1-num2 it depends on the order of if.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych I modify the answer, Thank you.

Comment: @XiaominWu thanks for your best help to me.
yeah i tested and it worked good.
you know Since I just started learning Python and I feel that I don't know a lot of topics, I want to know if there is a simpler way like what I did? I will be grateful

Comment: @Crashofs Just practice more and be curious

Comment: @XiaominWu Definitely on the eyes.
Thank you very much for your help